# How a function can access to the context of a class

Tags: javascript, class

this problem come from a big react/redux application. I'm trying to simplify it here.

I got a class, like:

```
import register from './registerActions';

Class Core {
    Constructor(url) {
        this.urlconfig = url;
    }

    getRegister() {
        return register();
    }
}
```

Can i access to the context of my class (in this case this.urlconfig) from my function register ? Or should i pass my context to the function as parameter ?

For now, if i try to call this.urlconfig in my register function, i got an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlconfig' of undefined
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you could `bind` it.

Comment: You can either call `register` in the context of the object (e.g. `register.call(this)`), or pass it as parameter (`register(this)`). If one is *"better"* then the other depends on the whole use-case.

Comment: `bind` usage that @Federkun mentioned can be seen [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html). And also, if you use redux as you mentioned, you can keep `urlconfig` as a state property and get it through there.

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, but i have tried to bind it, `this.register= register.bind(this);` and when i try to access to `this` in my register function, i still got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlconfig' of undefined`, same for `register.call(this);``
I'm i doing something bad ? Do you need more code to understand the problem ? I'm coding in js for less than 1 month, it's a bit hard for me. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone get the same issue, I finaly stored my configuration in the redux store.

I can access to it from any redux fonction, but i wasn't able to make the class work proprely.